# Java: retrieve SQLite3 Views source sql

Tags: java, sqlite

My *Java* application uses an in-memory *SQLite3* database which occasionally needs to be dumped on file.

This database contains both *Tables* and *Views*.
I need to know if there is a way, in *Java*, to retrieve the source *SQL* code of an *SQLite3* View.

So far, when dumping, I have been able to retrieve all *Views* and *Tables* from the database using *[DatabaseMetadata.getTables(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html)* but when it comes to *Views* I'm not able to obtain the source *SQL*.

For example, i could have a *View* named *Show_all* which retrieves all data from *Table_1*.

What i need on my file when the database is dumped is:

```
CREATE VIEW Show_all AS Select * From Table_1;
```

Comment: Thanks @CL your link really helped me.
What i was actually asking if there's some way in *Java* to achive the same result without the need to browse the table *sqlite_master* via *SQL*

Comment: There is no such mechanism in `DatabaseMetadata`.